# Get complete text of a truncated tooltip using javascript in chrome devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, google-chat

I am trying to fetch the complete list of users who have liked a post/comment in googleChat webapp. Right now, when you hover on the "like/thumbs up" icon, a tooltip shows only 10 names and rest are truncated with ellipsis with a count. I want to fetch the full list of users.
I have tried using innertext but it shows what you see on the UI but I believe there must be a way to fetch the complete list from somewhere. I am new to javascript and have been using scripts to fetch such hidden text/elements. Need some tips on the same.

Comment: If it's not truncated via CSS using `text-overflow` and `innerText`/`textContent` also returns the truncated text, then no, there's no way to get it from that element. So unless there's a public API returning all the users, there's no way.

Comment: I even tried checking the Network tab to see what all calls are being made when the tooltip shows up, none of them has response with those names, in fact it looks like they are encrypted.